# React charts but its looks special

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I achieve this kind of chart with any library with react js?

[image]

Comment: To achieve that effect you might have to do some customizations. Try using something like https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/, Try looking into something like apex charts

Answer (score 0):

there are n number of library available one of my favorite [is](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/) and your solution is [this](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/StackedAreaChart)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the library your'e using. Some of the top charting libraries JS are

1. E-charts (most extensible) (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/)
2. Novo charts (best designs) (https://nivo.rocks/)
3. Apex chart (easy to use) (https://apexcharts.com/)

All these libraries have reactJS wrappers so you can easily use them in your react app. It depends on your use case after exploring the libraries which ever suits you the most That chart you might want to use for this use is case would be **Stacked Area Chart**. These are all free